# What connections between machine learning and dynamical systems?

Tags: dynamical-systems, machine-learning, ergodic-theory

I have a background of ("pure") dynamical systems and ergodic theory, but I am switching to machine learning.

Can some machine learning questions be treated from a dynamical systems/ergodic theory viewpoint? What literature would you recommend for the intersection of these two fields? What kind of contribution would be possible?

I imagine something around coding of ergodic maps, which is connected with information theory, and seems to have some computer science flavor, but I do not know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try searching for topics concerning "Learning Dynamical Systems" and "Predictive State Representation." [Here is a possible reference](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~baveja/PSRmainpage.html).

I'm not sure Ergodicity in full generality is useful. If you're dealing with a Markov chain with a stationary distribution then there will be some ergodicity involved concerning the visitation of the steady states. Also, there's something called ["Ergodic Time Series"](http://vserver1.cscs.lsa.umich.edu/~crshalizi/notebooks/dependent-learning.html) which might be interesting to you.

Comment: thanks. maybe this can be a good starting point. http://cs.brown.edu/research/ai/dynamics/tutorial/Documents/DynamicalSystems.html